# How to avoid own address in Cc with `gnus-summary-followup`

Tags: gnus, email

I receive an email sent also to other people in Cc.  If I reply to it with `gnus-summary-followup`, Gnus includes me in the Cc list. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you want is the default if you've told emacs your email address
using `user-mail-address`. Another option is to set
`message-dont-replyto-names`

```
message-dont-reply-to-names is a variable defined in `message.el'.
Its value is nil

  You can customize this variable.
  This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
  version 24.3 of Emacs.

Documentation:
Addresses to prune when doing wide replies.
This can be a regexp, a list of regexps or a predicate function.
Also, a value of nil means exclude `user-mail-address' only.

If a function email is passed as the argument.
```

See [Wide-Reply](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/message/Wide-Reply.html) for more details (or `(info "(message)Wide Reply")`)

Comment: `message-dont-replyto-names` was the rescue. I did set `user-mail-address` to my private address, and set my business address in `gnus-posting-styles`.  Docs say this “overrides user-mail-address”. Well, apparently not really.

Comment: It does override user-mail-address, but it's possible/probable that it does so too late for `gnus-summary-followup` to be affected.